# One to many Foreign Key relation Sqlite

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite

So right now I'm trying to draw relations between 3 different tables using [sqlite](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin) I'm relatively new to sqlite but saw that you can draw relations by using foreign keys thus optimizing performance. So right now here is my sql statements creating my tables:

```
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shifts (
 shifts_id primary integer,
 shift_base_id integer,
 shift_site_id integer)';

'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sites (
 site_id primary integer, 
 site_info text,
 FOREIGN KEY(site_id) REFERENCES shifts(shift_site_id))';

 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bases (
 base_id primary integer, 
 base_info text,
 FOREIGN KEY(base_id) REFERENCES shifts(shift_base_id))';
```

So what I'm trying to do is draw relations between the child tables (sites and bases) with the parent table (shifts) by the id. The problem I'm running into is I'm getting a "foreign key mismatch" error. I read somewhere that in sqlite you can only REFERENCE a primary or unique key within the parent table. The problem with this is that multiple shifts can share the same sites and bases. For instance base_id could equal 1234 and multiple shifts would have shifts_base_id = 1234.

Also there will be times where a base_id in the bases table wont have a matching shift_base_id in the shifts table.

So my question is how to reference this one to many relation between multiple tables? And how to make that relation optional.

Answer (score 2):

You have your relationships backwards. You list the foreign keys in the table that reference the other tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shifts (
 shifts_id primary integer,
 shift_base_id integer,
 shift_site_id integer,
 FOREIGN KEY (shift_base_id) REFERENCES bases (base_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (shift_site_id) REFERENCES site (site_id));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Barmar, this makes sense and solved majority of my problem. The other one is making the relationship optional if at all possible. So if shift_base_id doesn't exist in the bases table it won't fail.

Comment: @JoeKomputer Just remove the foreign keys then. The entire point of FKs is to enforce relationships; making them 'optional' would be equivalent to not having them at all.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I could just remove the foreign key, but the reason I'm creating these FK relations is to speed up the SELECT query when I go to query the database WHERE site_id = shift_site_id. So if there was a way to make FK optional it would be beneficial in that sense? Or if there is another way of improving performance between tables that doesn't involve FKs I'd be open to suggestions.

Comment: @JoeKomputer FK's don't improve performance; they just check if a value exists in another table when inserting or updating a column.

Comment: I see @ColonelThirtyTwo I read somewhere that [indexing](https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) in sqlite improves performance. So if my relationships aren't shared within the same table, how would I index relations between multiple tables? I assumed FKs were the solution but maybe not.

Comment: @JoeKomputer Indexing just makes lookups faster. The `WHERE site_id = shift_site_id` will do a lookup on `site_id` (which, since it's a primary key, already has an index) with the value of `shift_site_id`.